# Where should one use WatiN DomContainer class?

Tags: watin

Could you please explain in simple words what DomContainer class means in WatiN and where should I use it in tests? I only found the definition in WatiN api docs:

> "This class hosts functionality for classes which are an entry point
>   to a document and its elements and/or frames."

Answer (score 0):

DomContainer is an abstract class inside the . The property in the other classes ( list, div etc ) shows the container of the DOM tree - WatiN.Core.IE, WatiN.Core.FireFox. It's used to identify the elements inside the tree. You can use it to start crawling the DOM tree, get the window handle, get the process id, insert handles and dispose of the browser.

Comment: Well, what's the difference then between

IE.DomContainer.Button(Find.ByText("sometext")).Click();

.. and

IE.Button(Find.ByText("sometext")).Click();